# Media Query: error using min-width

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using the following code in order to show certain element only in big screens:

```
.forkit, .forkit-curtain {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .forkit, .forkit-curtain {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

But when the screen is 1300px the element is shown and only is hidden when the width is 1250px so the media query min-width 1400px works also for screen sizes a bit lower what is a bad behaviour.

I don't know why the media query is getting a bad screen size. What is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I think we are going to need more than that to help you. Also your question title has `max-width`, but you don't use `max-width` anywhere in you code

Comment: Sorry, I've update the question

Answer (score 1):

i suspect the difference is not 50px but something closer to 20px.  What's more, I suspect that it does not react the same way for all browsers.  Try comparing the break points for Chrome and for Firefox.  If they are off about 20px, the difference is because:

IE, Firefox and Opera [follow the W3C spec](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201301/media_query_width_and_vertical_scrollbars/) of including the scrollbar width in the media query, where Webkit browsers do not.

So when you ask the browser to trigger at 1400px, it will trigger at approx 1383px in most browsers.

You can't force the browsers to treat it the same at the moment, so the best option is to modify your layout so that it is not so tightly tied to the widths in your media queries (add extra margin). With such a layout, when it triggers a few pixels early or late, it won't make as much of a difference.